# HTML5 Audio Streaming

Tags: php, html, audio-streaming

There has been some talk of this around stackoverflow before, but nothing really answered this question from what I have seen.
I am trying to implement a streaming audio web application. Almost identical to what WFMU has done with their player (http://wfmu.org/html5/player.php). 
All I have been able to figure out from their stream is they are piping the stream into PHP, don't know in what format, and then feeding this to jPlayer for HTML5 presentation to the client. 
They have this working awesome, but I am just unsure how they are feeding the audio into PHP and what they are doing within their PHP to present it in an acceptable format for HTML5. 
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. 
It looks like the PHP script just echos out an audio file (http://blogfiles.wfmu.org/DG/stream3.php).

Comment: As you point out in your question, this is not an HTML5 question. They are merely "playing" (as your browser plugin would) the audio source from the second URL you mention. If you try to download it with your browser, you'll see that it IS an mp3 (or ogg) which is being fed VERY slowly. The question is how to do that on the PHP side. The HTML5 side is trivial and already solved.

Comment: Yep, that was my ultimate question. Sorry if it became somewhat blurred in that long winded question up there. Try and determine what PHP functions they are using to call the audio, which may be just a simple fread. Which in that case I would need to know if they are doing a live feed compiled to an MP3 before any web is involved.

Comment: @MikeSoule - did you make any progress on this since you asked the question?  Anything you could share?  I am wanting to do something similar.

Comment: @Jonathan Apologies for the delayed response! Yes, I made good head way. I ended up not writing the buffering and streaming in PHP and just used HTLM5 with a Flash failover. I accomplished this using the SoundManager2 Javascript API. This works very well, here is an example I used for testing: http://soule.biz/bombshelter.fm/player/. The CSS isn't too pretty, but you can get the idea of how SM2 works by looking at my source. They have tons of examples on their site as well. By the way I am streaming with Icecast and pass SM2 an MP3 encoded stream from that server. Let me know if you have ?s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to use PHP.  For the client, all that matters is you send the appropriate content type, and actual content.  In this case, audio/mpeg (MP3), or OGG for Firefox (which, isn't working for them right now, but it definitely can).

I suspect the reason that they are using PHP to relay the stream, is that they are using SHOUTcast as the streaming server.  Doing some poking around, I found this:  http://mp3stream.wfmu.org:8000/

Note that when you hit that URL in your browser, you get the basic information page.  However, if you hit this with an audio player, you get the stream.  The SHOUTcast server decides this based on the User-Agent string.  If it contains "Mozilla" anywhere in the User-Agent, then it returns this page.  If it doesn't, then it returns the stream.  So, for an HTML5 audio player, it would use the browser's User-Agent (which contains Mozilla) and would be unable to access the stream.  I suspect their PHP script is what gets around the problem.

The PHP script would use cURL, connect to the streaming server with its own User-Agent (can be anything, as long as it isn't "Mozilla"), and relay chunk by chunk to the browser that hit the PHP script.  Piece of key-lime-pie.

Comment: That sounds like the solution. Much appreciated, this should at least get me on the right track as I already have an IceCast server streaming. Thank you.