# jPlayer and Shoutcast Configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, shoutcast

I am trying to set up JPlayer plugin and Shoutcast. According to their website this is possible to do.

> How do I get jPlayer to play a SHOUTCast stream? You need to setMedia
>   to the stream URL. For example, SHOUTcast server:
>   http://mp3-vr-128.as34763.net/ MP3 stream URL:
>   http://mp3-vr-128.as34763.net/;stream/1

I have tried to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a:"http://77.68.106.224:8018;stream/1",
                oga:"http://77.68.106.224:8018"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },


        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4a, oga, mp3", 
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

I do not get any output with my settings. Is anyone using JPlayer for a shoutcast Stream, or can anyone suggest a  player that doesn't need php.

Comment: are you sure that swfPath is correct??

Comment: The path is correct. I used the demo files to confirm before i posted my question.   The stream is live http://77.68.106.224:8018

Comment: I'm not sure but I have been into similar trouble and that was because of supplied types , try removing 'mp3' from supplied types and let me know what happens :)

Comment: This is very strange, nothing happens at all.  Do you know any other player that doesn't require php?

Comment: I wish this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305974/html5-audio-streaming

Comment: can anyone help me with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289162/onclick-swf-player-database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sweet vibes on this station!

You're almost there, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/FBNZa/) to see your stream working in jPlayer.. Shoutcast outputs audio in MP3 format, not M4a or OGG.. you need constructor code more like that below..

One important thing to know is that the Flash plugin when using IE8 sometimes spends *minutes* buffering the audio.. You click play, think it isn't working then suddenly find your audio starts playing after three minutes.. The good news is that Chrome, Safari and Firefox play the stream almost immediately.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://77.68.106.224:8018;stream/1"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },


        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3", 
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works....I truly appreciate this. Have a great day and a happy new year.

Comment: When I replaced the IP to my radio ip then your Fiddle works for me, but when I copied the code to local file (test.html) - I got Flash error #2060 and its not working :((( jquery and Jplayer.swf URL are the same.. why?

Comment: Do you know how to get the song information like artist and song name to appear?

Comment: i think jPlayer will only pick up the audio stream, not the associated metadata like 'artist' and 'title'.. but check..

Comment: I get an update error on the fiddle - "Update Required To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your Flash plugin." - my Flash player is updated and current.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need a solution. We used the j player in the past but with Chrome updates and problems with flash and other browsers, Win 10 and flash issues we moved away from it. DO NOT CHANGE ANY PUNCUATIONS. Just paste the code into your website.

We now use a simple media player code. You'll have to put in your IP and Port #.

```
     <div id="wb_MediaPlayer1">
<audio src="http://YOUR IP ADDRESS:YOUR PORT/;" id="MediaPlayer1" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
</audio></div>
```

This code is included in our Widgets service at [My Radio Hosting](https://myradiohosting.com) if you would like to take a look.

Hope this helps!