# Getting Error #2060 on localhost (jPlayer.swf)

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, localhost, jplayer

My problem is:

- [This fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786563/jplayer-and-shoutcast-configuration) is working for me.
- But when I copy-paste the same code (includeing correct paths to jquery, jplayer and Jplayer.swf) I am getting an error:

## ActionScript Error #2060

```
SecurityError: Error #2060: Naruszenie obszaru izolowanego: element wywołujący ExternalInterface http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf nie może uzyskać dostępu do null.
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_evalJS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
    at Jplayer/init()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Why would the same code work on a remote server (like jsfiddle) but a local file throws an error?

How can I run this code on my local machine?

## This is how test.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Play a Shoutcast stream - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
  $(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        swfPath: "Jplayer.swf",
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://94.23.108.1:8018/;stream/1" });
        },
        supplied: "mp3"
    });
  });//]]>  

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-current-time">
        </div>
        <div class="jp-duration">
        </div>
        <ul class="jp-toggles">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-title">
        <ul>
          <li>Testing</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-no-solution">
        <span>Update Required</span> To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using the same version of jquery that fiddle uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this post](http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/01/01/securityerror-error-2060-security-sandbox-violation-externalinterface-caller/) I found the solution was:

> Previewing in
>
> ```
> http://localhost
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> file://
> ```
>
>  You can view these files on localhost instead of the file system by changing the following,